# Pandas. 2 col dataframe. Get intersection matrix (all to all, from col #1)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe like this one (basically two columns: first contains blogger id and second one contains followers):

```
blogger follower
A   c
A   d
A   e
A   f
A   g
A   h
A   i
A   j
A   k
B   c
B   f
B   g
B   l
B   m
B   n
B   o
B   p
B   q
B   r
B   s
B   t
B   k
C   a
C   k
C   r
C   g
C   t
C   c
C   p
C   y
C   z
C   w
```

What I want to get is a square matrix with all-to-all intersection count, like this:

```
    A   B   C
A   -   4   3
B   4   -   6
C   3   6   -
```

I'm not a skilled pandas user and all I achieved is doing this by using 2 loops and np.intersect which I believe is not efficient. I've been trying to play with pivot_table(), crosstab() and groupby() - no luck, so unfortunately there is no code to share. Maybe someone here knows an efficient solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perform a self-`merge`, followed by `crosstab`ulation operation.

```
i = df.merge(df, on='follower') 
j = pd.crosstab(i.blogger_x, i.blogger_y)
```

```
j

blogger_y  A   B   C
blogger_x           
A          9   4   3
B          4  13   6
C          3   6  10
```

Of course, the diagonals aren't `-`, but that's easy.

```
j = j.astype(object)
j.values[[np.arange(j.shape[0])] * 2] = '-'
```

```
j

blogger_y  A  B  C
blogger_x         
A          -  4  3
B          4  -  6
C          3  6  -
```

Note that this ruins performance, because your columns are now object type, which is the only way to mix values of different types in the same column.

Comment: That's awesome! Works tons of times faster. Thank you!